# android-How to align actionbar menus and navigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

these are my menus :

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/search"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/newadd"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/newadd"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/sort"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_sort_by_size"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

when I run the app , all 3 of them are on the right side of actionbar , How can I make  them to move to left side of actionbar ?

also , I've an navigationDrawer , the icon is on the left side and I want to move it to the right side , How can I do so ?

I don't have any search on my actionbar .

How can I do so ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom views for actionbar

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

actionbar xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

set these methods for actionbar to make navigation drawer home icon visible

```
  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#56B1D8"))); //$NON-NLS-1$
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            // actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            // getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer);
            // navigation icon on actionbar
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setIcon(null);
```

Comment: Iv'e tried that , What should be the content of custom_actionbar layout ? for making 3 image buttons on actionbar and navigationDrawer ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're a right-to-left reader and trying to support such.  As for the app as a whole I believe it takes its cues from your device's selected language and locale.  Forcing right-to-left?  IDK how to do that, but to flip the actionbar as you've described I suspect that's what you'd be doing.

Aside from that just make sure you're using `start` and `end` vs. `left` and `right` for other alignments.  Both start and end will honor your devices settings where as left and right will not.

Comment: could you give me an example ? where should I put start and end vs. left and right  ?

Comment: Any place where alignment or gravity is used.